# Convert json in array in php issue

Tags: php, json

I have JSON:

```
[{"name":"point","visibility":false},{"name":"php_first_table","visibility":true}]
```

I do:

```
$Arr = json_decode($json,true);
```

I get:

```
Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => point
        [visibility] => 
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => php_first_table
        [visibility] => 1
    )

)
```

How to save true and false in boolean form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It already is in boolean form. Try to use `var_dump($array[0]['visibility']);` and it'll output `bool(true)` or `bool(false)`.

`print_r` automatically converts the boolean to `1` for true and `(empty)` for false when outputting, but it doesn't change the data type.

You can use `var_dump` on your array to get a better output:

```
<?php
    $array = array(
        'booleanTrue' => true,
        'booleanFalse' => false,
        'integer' => 1
    );
    var_dump($array);
    print_r($array);

    /*
        array(3) {
          ["booleanTrue"]=>
          bool(true)
          ["booleanFalse"]=>
          bool(false)
          ["integer"]=>
          int(1)
        }
        Array
        (
            [booleanTrue] => 1
            [booleanFalse] => 
            [integer] => 1
        )
    */
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/IuNIUc3I)

**Edit**:

Here's a function to give you a nicer/more compact `var_dump` output very similar to `print_r`:

```
<?php
    function var_dump_r($variable, $return = false) {
        ob_start();
        var_dump($variable);
        $output = preg_replace('/\["([^"]+)"\]/', '[$1]', preg_replace('/\s*=>\s*/', ' => ', ob_get_clean()));

        if (!$return) {
            echo $output;
        }
        return $return;
    }

    var_dump_r(array(
        'booleanTrue' => true,
        'booleanFalse' => false,
        'integer' => 1
    ));

    /*
        array(3) {
          [booleanTrue] => bool(true)
          [booleanFalse] => bool(false)
          [integer] => int(1)
        }
    */
?>
```

Comment: Yeah you are right. Don't know this fact about print_r before. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[It looks fine to me](http://3v4l.org/neRDm).

Are you using `print_r` or something similar to print it? (Pro-tip: don't).

Answer (score 1):

TRUE is always a value greater than 0 and FALSE is 0, so you only have to check

```
if ($visibility) {
   // do something
}
```